# Is who your employer is a public/accessable knowledge in Germany

Tags: employment, germany, data-protection

Assuming you don't have LinkedIn or any social network that says who your current employer is, can your previous employer somehow find out through a certain source or access this information from somewhere to learn who you are currently employed with? Or how.

For example, there are agencies in Germany such as Job-Center, Agentur für Arbeit, or immigration-office that normally have such information, but I wonder if they would disclose such information given your previous employer's query from them.

In general, how easy it can be for a previous employer to access such knowledge about you in Germany.

Comment: Are you strictly limiting your question to government information? For example, many people appear on their employer's websites making it very obvious. Also, why would the previous employer want to know other than idle curiosity?

Comment: Yes, but the previous employer needs to be Germany’s intelligence agency.

Comment: Why would they want to know? If it is idle curiosity, privacy will win. If they have substantive reason to think that you carried business secrets to a competitor, the competitor might have to answer at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## That is private.

Who you work for is not information that is disclosed publicly by any state actor in Germany, just like your taxes. In fact, that or who you are employed at is often regarded as personal and private information.

## Nigh impossible through agencies

Public agencies like the Fiskus (tax), Agentur für Arbeit, and immigration are not allowed to give any information about a person to anyone but that person or another agency that has the right to that information.

Yes, (generally speaking) the tax office may not even say that a person **exists** (or doesn't) and what their tax number is to anyone but the person in question.

Comment: Most likely they are also not allowed to say that a person doesn’t exist.

Comment: @gnasher729 indeed, generally speaking.